# fluid facebook "like" button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a facebook "like" button on my website, I'd like to make it fluid as the container it is in is fluid and when the container is smaller than the button there is an overflow. I'd like to keep the text and buttons the same size, id just like to have the overflowing text break off to the next line... there is plenty of results in a google search for customizing this, but I havent found anything that will do line breaks according to a fluid width. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're after, but text wrapping should happen automatically with something like this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
#wrapper { width: 250px }
#like { border: none; width: 100%; background-color: transparent }
</style>

<div id='wrapper'>
<iframe id='like' src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=xxx' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
</div>
```

You can change the width of the wrapper div and the Like text will wrap as needed.

The XFBML doesn't work the same way, but you can cut off the text by fixing a width:

```
<style type='text/css'>
#like { width: 104px; overflow: hidden }
</style>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:like id='like' href="xxx" send="true" show_faces="false" layout="standard"></fb:like>
```

Comment: that didn't really work, is there a way to just turn off the text that says "so and so and x amount of people like this", all i really want is the like and send button there to begin with, and that will slim it down to the necessary size.

Comment: I didn't realize you needed an XFBML version. The text wrap won't work, but I edited my answer for a way to cut the text off completely.

Comment: to be honest i have no idea what the difference is between xfbml and what ever other options there are :/ the fix worked, it also helped me realize that I need to get some fresh code from fb cause there are all sorts of blank areas, such as href and so on. Thanks!